# Enter button gets trigrred while enter new line in input form

Tags: php, html, forms

im working on a project where a user can describe his location in multiple lines but when i press enter button for new line in input form it gets submitted into database. i feel myself stucked here. help me to get rid of this please

my html code is:

```
<form method="POST" id="name-form">
  <div class="h4">Describe Location</div>
  <input type="text" value='Describe Location' name="disc" class="input-formm">
  <input type="submit" value="discribe" name="discribe" class="edit-button">
</form>
```

and my php code is :

```
if (isset($_POST['discribe'])) {
    $disc =  htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['disc']));
    $qry =  "UPDATE `Location` SET disc=:disc WHERE city = :city";
    $result = $conn->prepare($qry);
    $result->bindParam(':disc', $disc, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $result->bindParam(':city', $city, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $result->execute();
}
```

please help me

Comment: Replace your `<input>` with a `<textarea>` element - which is actually multiline

Comment: textarea is working but when i fetch data from database it showing in single line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using "<input type="text" ...>" you can use "<textarea ..>" markup. It can be easily used in forms and shouldn't submit on enter while in this text area.

Answer (score 0):

if you go with input type text and do not want any textarea then just used this jquery code

```
$('form [name="disc"]').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```